# How do I call my method in html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I want to call my method in my mvc view. I have a method called SavePersoon wich has to save the changed data into my database. This is my code from my services:

```
public bool SavePersoon(PersoonModel persoon)
    {
        bool result = true;


        db.Persoon.AddOrUpdate(persoon.GetPoco());


        db.SaveChanges();
        return result;
    }
```

This is the button who has to be pressed and then this code above has to deal the work itself.

The view:

```
<button type="button" id="btnSaveChanges" class="btn btn-primary">Opslaan</button>
```

Do I have to use something similair like `<asp:LinkButton...`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. pls explain the scenario better.

Comment: Show your view. Do you have a form? And you need `type="submit"` to submit a form

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Ajax , Something like this

```
$("#btnSaveChanges").on("click",function(){
   $.ajax({
     url:"/controllerName/SavePersoon",
     data:$("#formName").serialize(),
     cache:false,
     type:"POST",
     error:function(){
        alert("Error");
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Razor view engaine, you can make your method  return an action result and call it from the view  using Html.Actionlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things:

Use the HTML Helpers that ASP.Net MVC provides to create a form which posts to the required method, something like 'Save' of the controller 'Person':

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" })) {
<div>
     <!-- Your HTML, this could for example be a text field for the person its name -->

     @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</div>
}
```

This will create a form tag for you, something like `<form action="person/save" method="post"> ... your HTML & the submit button ... </form>`

An alternative is to use Ajax to prevent the page from refreshing as stated in the above post.

```
$("#btnSaveChanges").on("click",function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Person")', // Again an MVC HTML Helper to create a URL
     data:$("#Name").val(), // Posts the value of a text field with ID "Name"
     cache:false,
     type:"POST",
     success: funcion(returnValue) {
          // Do something with the result.
     }
     error:function(){
        alert("Error");
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: In a JavaScript section like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSaveChanges").on("click",function(){
        // Your code
    }
</script>

I must add that I'm using JQuery here inside JavaScript.

Comment: I've updated the first part as it requires a HTML submit control which submits the form its content to the action url.